# What happened to the Inquisitorius?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In *Star Wars: Rebels*, the Inquisitorius was the main enemy of the rebels in the first two seasons. During that time, Kanan Jarrus kills the Grand Inquisitor and Maul kills 3 other Inquisitors (the 5th and 8th Brothers, and 7th Sister).

Were there any other Inquisitors, and if so, **why didn’t they try to kill the rebels?**

Comment: Were there 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 6th siblings?

Comment: They came here to do two things: kill the rebels, and chew gum. Turns out they still had quite a lot of gum left.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - and I guess they were all out of revenge as well, that magical elixir that restores one from the dead apparently <eyeroll>

Comment: The Inquisitors were meant to kill the leftover Jedi and hunt force sensitive children, not to fight the rebels perse, they only fought them because well... they had 2 force users with them

Comment: @Mrc4t987, if their job is to kill force sensitives who won’t join their order, then why wouldn’t they keep attacking the rebels

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **Inquisitorius** hunted down Jedi and other force-sensitive beings who were a potential threat to the Empire. We have seen many of them on assignment through a variety of media, most eventually meeting their demise. Here is a list of all the inquisitors who did not appear in *Star Wars: Rebels* and why they did not appear later to hunt down Kanan, Ezra and co.

Warning: Spoilers for *Jedi: Fallen Order*, *Jedi: Survivor* (this one is in a spoiler tag since the game is still pretty new), *Obi-Wan* (TV Series), Ashoka (Novel), Tales of the Jedi (TV Series),  Darth Vader (Comic)

**[Second Sister](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Second_Sister?so=search)**

The Second Sister was seen in *Jedi: Fallen Order* as she took the lead in the hunt for Cal Kestis. He failure led to her death at the hands of Darth Vader in approx 14 BBY.

[image: Still of the Second Sister in a cutscene in Jedi: Fallen Order]

**[Third Brother](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Third_Brother)**

Nothing is known about him. The only reference is he was mentioned briefly in the **Star Wars Encyclopedia**.

**[Third Sister](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Reva_Sevander?so=search)**

The Third Sister is involved in the hunt for Obi-Wan Kenobi in *Obi-Wan* which takes place in 9 BBY. After betraying the Inquisitors and Darth Vader, she leaves to go off on her own. Her fate is unknown at this time.

[image: Still of the Second Sister in the Obi-Wan series]

**[Fourth Sister](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Fourth_Sister)**

The Fourth Sister is involved in the hunt for Obi-Wan Kenobi in *Obi-Wan* which takes place in 9 BBY. Little is known about her after, however Rebel [Lina Graf](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lina_Graf) acquired her armor and used it to impersonate the Fourth Sister around 2 BBY.

[image: Still of the Fourth Sister in the Obi-Wan series]

**[Sixth Brother](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sixth_Brother?so=search)**

Sixth Brother was the primary antagonist in the *Ahsoka* novel. He died in a duel with Ahsoka on Raada. Ahsoka used his kyber crystals to forge her white lightsabers.

[image: Image of the Sixth Brother]

**[Ninth Sister](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ninth_Sister?so=search)**

The Ninth Sister was involved in the hunt for Cal Kestis.

> In *Jedi:Survivor* she was killed by Cal in a duel in 9 BBY on Coruscant.

[image: Still of the Ninth Sister in a cutscene in Jedi: Fallen Order]

**[Tenth Brother](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tenth_Brother?so=search)**

The Tenth Brother is seen in the *Jedi of the Republic – Mace Windu* and *Darth Vader* comics. He was killed by Purge Troopers in 18 BBY on Coruscant.

[image: Screenshot of a comic panel featuring the Tenth Brother]

**Unidentified Inquisitors**

A masked Inquisitor was seen in *Tales of the Jedi* S1E6. It is unknown if he is supposed to be the Sixth Brother as the scenes have many parallels. He was killed by Ahsoka Tano.

[image: Still of a masked Inquisitor from the Tales of the Jedi series]

A [male Twi'lek inquisitor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_Twi%27lek_Inquisitor) was seen in the *Darth Vader* comics. He was killed by Vader in 14 BBY on Coruscant.

[image: Screenshot of a comic panel featuring a Male Twi'lek Inquisitor]

[Iskat Akaris](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Iskat_Akaris) was a female Inquisitor of unknown number from the *Darth Vader* comics. She was killed by Vader in 14 BBY on Coruscant.

[image: Screenshot of a comic panel featuring Iskat Akaris]

An [unknown female Inquisitor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_female_Inquisitor) is mentioned in the *Force and Destiny RPG* [Ghosts of Dathomir](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ghosts_of_Dathomir) adventure book. She was killed by her nightsister apprentice at an unknown time. (I dont think this counts as canon but I thought I would include it)

**In Summation:**

Why did no other Inquisitors come to hunt after the crew in *Rebels*? Well, most were dead. There is no indication of Inquisitors being replaced after death. So it's likely when the 5th and 8th Brothers, and 7th Sister meet their end, there were no more Inquisitors left. If there were, it's possible they were on other missions at the time.